# Updating <div> text with value from the previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm redirecting the user from another page when they click the "Edit" button using the code below.

```
$('#editListButton').click(function(){ 
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/yyy.php";  //redirect

   // Changes that need to be made
   $('#defaultText').remove();
   $('#orderList').append('<p' + 'message'  + '</p>');
});
```

The page redirects to the predefined link, after which I need update a html `<div>` tag with text. But the code coming from the other page does nothing. How can change the text in the div tag?

Comment: Where is the "html div" on page 1 or page 2? If it's on page 2 then you'll need to pass the text and operation in the query string of the call to page 2.

Comment: Page A is the page with Edit button, Page B is the page that I redirected user when button clicked. Html div is on Page B. Can you explain a little more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to pass information from one page to another. To give an idea of the concept, somewhat in relation to the question posted, here's one:

Page A:

```
$('#editListButton').click(function(){ 
  window.location.href = "http://localhost/yyy.php?action=remove&value=" + 
    encodeURIComponent('ashdahjsgfgasfas');    
});
```

Page B:

```
var action = /(?:\?|&)action=([^&$]+)/.exec(location.search)
if ( 'remove' === action[1] ) {
    var value = /(?:\?|&)value=([^&$]+)/.exec(location.search)
    $('#defaultText').remove();
    $('#orderList').append('<p>' + value[1]  + '</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass it in the url.

```
$('#editListButton').click(function(){ 
   window.location.href = "http://localhost/yyy.php?message";  //redirect
});
```

Then on the other page

```
var url = window.location.href.split('?');
var msg = url[1];

$('#defaultText').remove();
$('#orderList').append('<p>' + msg  + '</p>');
```

Comment: Yepp, I think this is the right solution. But what you mean with "on the other page". I have only one js file, so I have to create another one for the second part of the code?

Comment: you could just write a `<script>` block at the bottom of the page. Or include your script file . at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2):

Once you've triggered an operation that's going to reload the entire page, browsers (not all, but it seems like most) will just quit doing anything to the current page, essentially ignoring any DOM updates from the event loop.

To get around this, it generally works to delay the redirect with a short timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "http://localhost/yyy.php"; 
}, 1);
```

Now the browser doesn't know that the page is to be reloaded, so it'll obey your DOM update request.

*edit* — If what you're expecting (and it's not really clear from the OP, but it's hinted at in a comment below) is that the code after updating the location should affect the *new* page, well that's just not how things work. You can put that code in the new page (and pass parameters via the URL you're loading, if necessary) and have it run there, or else you can change the architecture completely and load your new code via ajax.

Comment: I updated the code like below but still do nothing, where is the mistake?$('#editListButton').click(function(){  
       setTimeout(function() {
             window.location.href = "http://localhost/yyy.php"; 
       }, 1);
       
       $('#defaultText').remove();
       $('#orderList').append('<p' + 'ashdahjsgfgasfas'  + '</p>'); 
        
    });

Comment: Also html div is on the redirected page

Comment: @user3235456 one mistake is `'<p'` instead of `'<p>'` but otherwise it should work. [Here is a CodePen to demonstrate.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/JozJZy) In that one, I added a 2-second delay, and fixed the `<p>` problem, but otherwise it's your code. You did not post your HTML, and you have not said anything about console errors, so there might be all sorts of problems I can't know about.

Comment: @user3235456 if the `<div>` you're trying to target with that JavaScript is on the new page, it is impossible for your code to work. You have to put that code on the new page.