# How to perform query string on the page loaded inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My case is simple, am loading a page in div as shown below. Parent.html page contains the loadpage() function to load the child page in `includedContent` div element. Parent.html url itself has some parameter append with it.

`Parent.html?data=123`

```
<script>
function loadpage() {

           $("#includedContent").load("child.html",{data1='one'});
        }
</script>
```

As expected the child page loaded inside the div and am performing querystring at the child page body onload event, in which both `location.search` and `window.location.href` returns the query of parent page `data=123` but the expected content is `data1='one'`, so how to get the url content of child page.

Comment: I think `load` doesn't change page URL. It just gets html back from server and sets in selected element. You will always get query string of parent page. You will need to use iframe to perform that kind of operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318888/updating-div-text-with-value-from-the-previous-page ... same principles apply in this question

Comment: @RohanJ i go with iframe thanks